# What free software can I use to solve a system of linear equations containing an unknown?

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems, gap

> **Question**: What free software can I use to solve a system of linear equations $M\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$ where the entries of $\mathbf{y}$ vary with an unknown quantity $n$?

Presumably I could do this in Maple or Mathematica, but I don't have access to these packages at this time.

*Motivation*: In an attempt to answer my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387707/139), I've set up a system of linear equations where:

- $M$ is a $30 \times 27$ $(0,1)$-matrix.
- $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of length $27$, which I'd like to attempt to solve for (the entries represent the number of symbols of a given type in a given block in my problem).  If this method were to work, there should be no solutions.
- $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector of length $27$, where the entries are either $0$, $(n-2k)^2$, $(n-2k)k$, or $k^2$, where $k=\lfloor n/3 \rfloor+1$.

I can solve this in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) using `SolutionMat` for a given value of $n$.  But I would like to do it symbolically, which would instead result in a proof for all $n$.  I don't believe this is possible in GAP (since `x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");` followed by `SolutionMat([1],[x]);` returns an error).

Comment: Are there any bounds for values of _k_ and _n_, and for the entries of **x**? Also, are they integers?

Comment: For my problem they're arbitrary positive integers, but GAP didn't find any non-integer solutions for small $n$, so I don't think there's any solutions (let alone integral solutions).  There are bounds for the entries of $\mathbf{x}$ (they can't be more than $k^2$).  I'd like to find that there's no solution for any value of $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).  You can use it through a web browser even.

Comment: I got this to work fairly easily (I downloaded the whole 630MB package).  I used the method described [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/constructions/linear_algebra.html), `var('x,y,z,a')`, etc., which says I'm using maxima through sage.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). It is pretty handy and easy to use. It is an opensource version of [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/). It is not completely clear from your question, if you want to solve the linear system with $n$ being an unknown quantity/variable(i.e., treating $n$ as a symbol) or if you want to solve the linear system by letting $n$ take on different values. Either way, if you want to use $n$ as an unknown variable, then you should use `syms` to treat $n$ as a symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You should give [Sequalator](http://sequalator.blogspot.com) a try.
It is capable of solving thousands of Linear Simultaneous Equations with great precision and speed.
On my mediocre laptop it is able to solve 1000 equations just below a second.

EDIT: I am the developer of Sequalator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Python programming, you can try SymPy (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) and see how far you can go with it.